# Why am I getting a Unresolved compilation problems error with ApplicationContext and ClassPathXmlApplicationContext in my Spring program?

Tags: spring

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
ApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type
Employee cannot be resolved to a variable

```
at SpringDemo1/com.mypackage.Client.main(Client.java:21)
```

can't able to run the program